# SQL select of records from table A but not in table B

Tags: sql, select, db2

Please, can someone help me find the SQL statement that
select all records in TABLE_A except those whose combination of FIELD_1, FIELD_2 is not present in TABLE_B.

(In DB2)

Comment: Tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * from table_a ta
where not exists (select * from table_b tb
                  where tb.field_1 = ta.field_1
                    and tb.field_2 = ta.field_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use not exists:

```
select * from table_A where not exists (select * from table_B 
                  where table_B.field_1 = table_A.field_1
                    and  table_B.field_2 = ta.field_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anti-join. For example:

```
select *
from table_a a
left join table_b b on b.field_1 = a.field_1 and b.field_2 = a.field_2
where b.field_1 is null
```